# Why the time cost nearly the same for 1 million rows insertion between 100 transactions and 10000 transactions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Currently I'm working on MySQL performance investigation, speaking of the MySQL performance, I don't want the round trip to be involved, so I tested something like this:

```
drop table if exists tbl;
create table tbl (c1 bigint, c2 varchar(32), c3 datetime);
drop procedure if exists run_insert;
delimiter //
create procedure run_insert()
begin
    declare i int default 0;
    start transaction;
    while i < 1000000
    do
        insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
        set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    commit;
end//
delimiter ;
call run_insert();
```

It went out

```
mysql>
mysql> drop table if exists tbl;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql>
mysql> create table tbl (c1 bigint, c2 varchar(32), c3 datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql>
mysql> drop procedure if exists run_insert;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create procedure run_insert()
    -> begin
    ->     declare i int default 0;
    ->     start transaction;
    ->     while i < 1000000
    ->     do
    ->         insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
    ->         set i = i + 1;
    ->     end while;
    ->     commit;
    -> end//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
mysql>
mysql> call run_insert();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.26 sec)

mysql>
```

Not bad for 20 seconds, but we all know that there is only 1 transaction despite of 1 million rows insertion, if we break it into 1 million transactions, the metrics will drop down heavily, but how the number of transactions impact the final metrics? so I did another 2 test

Break it into 100 transactions:

```
begin
    declare i int default 0;
    set autocommit = 0;
    while i < 1000000
    do
        insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
        set i = i + 1;
        if i % 10000 = 0 then
            commit;
        end if;
    end while;
    commit;
end//
```

Break it into 10000 transactions:

```
begin
    declare i int default 0;
    set autocommit = 0;
    while i < 1000000
    do
        insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
        set i = i + 1;
        if i % 100 = 0 then
            commit;
        end if;
    end while;
    commit;
end//
```

100 transaction VS 10000 transaction, with the same amount of data, there must be something different, but

```
mysql> call run_insert();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (22.86 sec)
```

VS

```
mysql> call run_insert();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.98 sec)
```

For the first and second code respectively, I don't get it, how it comes hardly any difference?

**Update** after I found something, I think this is the way how MySQL transaction works, first you let every insert a transaction, then next time you merge every two insert into a transaction, and then you merge every four insert into a transaction..., in this progress, the first several steps will bring significant performance improvement, but last ones will not, this is the reason why 100 transaction has not much diff with 10000 transactions

```
drop procedure if exists run_insert;
delimiter //
create procedure run_insert(in step int)
begin
    declare i int default 0;
    drop table if exists tbl;
    create table tbl (c1 bigint, c2 varchar(32), c3 datetime);
    set autocommit = 0;
    while i < 1000000
    do
        insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
        set i = i + 1;
        if i % step = 0 then
            commit;
        end if;
    end while;
    commit;
end//
delimiter ;
call run_insert(pow(2, 0));
call run_insert(pow(2, 1));
call run_insert(pow(2, 2));
call run_insert(pow(2, 3));
call run_insert(pow(2, 4));
call run_insert(pow(2, 5));
call run_insert(pow(2, 6));
call run_insert(pow(2, 7));
call run_insert(pow(2, 8));
call run_insert(pow(2, 10));
call run_insert(pow(2, 11));
call run_insert(pow(2, 12));
call run_insert(pow(2, 12));
call run_insert(pow(2, 14));
call run_insert(pow(2, 15));
call run_insert(pow(2, 16));
call run_insert(pow(2, 17));
call run_insert(pow(2, 18));
call run_insert(pow(2, 19));
call run_insert(pow(2, 20));

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 0));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1 min 7.63 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 1));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (46.00 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 2));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (35.13 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 3));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (28.12 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (25.10 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 5));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (23.87 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 6));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (22.48 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 7));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.70 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.84 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 10));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.71 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 11));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (22.78 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 12));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.84 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 12));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.48 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 14));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.93 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 15));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.59 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 16));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.76 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 17));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.07 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 18));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (21.37 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 19));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.77 sec)

mysql> call run_insert(pow(2, 20));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (20.87 sec)
```

Comment: The `start transaction` statement needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: After you do the first commit, you're doing all the rest of the inserts without transactions, because you don't start another transaction.

Comment: Please post the corrected code and the new results.

Comment: Just updated, currently I can not upload the image because I am located in a place behind firewall

Answer (score 0):

You're still not starting and committing the transactions properly.

When `i == 0`, the modulus condition succeeds, you start a transaction, insert a row, then commit that transaction.

On the next iteration, when `i == 1`, you don't start a transaction, you insert a row, then don't commit anything.

So you're doing every insert in its own transaction.

You need to start a new transaction after every commit, except the last one.

```
begin
    declare i int default 0;
    start transaction;
    while i < 1000000
    do
        insert into tbl values(i, rand(), now() + interval 1 second);
        if i % 100 = 0 then
            commit;
            if i != 999999 then
                begin transaction;
            end if;
        end if;
        set i = i + 1;
    end while;
    commit;
end//
```

Comment: I should not use `start transaction`, I should `set autocommit = 0` and execute `commit` every X iterators

Comment: I think that's effectively equivalent.

Comment: strange, the question still stands, no `start` now, exec `set auto` before loop, exec `commit` `if i % 100 = 0`, nearly the same `if i % 10000 = 0`

Comment: finally after so much test, there should be difference, between 1 rpt(row per transaction) and 2 rpt, and less difference fbetween 2 rpt and 4rpt,.... even less for 100 rpt and 10000 rpt, there should be, it is just too small the number of